# Remote EJB Lookup Between two ears in glassfish 2.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I have 2 EARS. The first EAR contains all the jars with the interfaces (EAR_INTERFACE.ear).
These interfaces are marked as remote.

The second ear contains the ejbs(EAR_EJB). These ejbs implement the @remote interfaces from the first ear.The EJBs are stateless and have mappedName.
In order to get the reference to the ejb i do a jndi lookup using the mappedName of the ejb in my second EAR.

Here i face the issue, i am not able to get the reference to the Remote EJBs.
If the interface and ejbs are in the same EAR, then lookup is successful, but it fails between different EARs.

I am using glassfish server v2.1, ejb 3.0.

I searched for this issue and found out about parent child EARs.
Will this solve my issue. If yes how to implement this. Do i need to mention something in application.xml of the EAR.

Please suggest me the best option to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is issue with glassfish 2.1

If the interface is not in the same module as the ejb is the lookup fails. The interface is not loaded by the classloader and so stub is not generated.

My ejb jar was in a ear and the interface was in another jar.
Some how i found out workaround for this issue. Before deployement of the ear, keep the interface jar in the domain/domain1/lib/ext, restart the glassfish. Deploy the ear containing the ejbs. After deployment is done successfully, copy the interface jar to the application/j2ee-apps/ and re-start the glassfish. Then if i try to do lookup, the lookup succeds.

If someone faced out similar issue or has some better workaround, plase reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How do you do the JNDI Lookup?

We have some GF 2.1 Server and if the EJB's are in different projects, the only solution was to look it up like this:

```
RemoteInterface bean = null;
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "host");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "port");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
RemoteInterface bean = (RemoteInterface)
ctx.lookup("full.qualified.name.RemoteInterface");
```

Comment: What about the interfaces. Did you kept the Interfaces of the remote ejbs in the same module or in seperate module ?

Were the ejbs and their interfaces in the same archive file while deployment or were they in different archive files ?

Comment: I have 3 Maven projects for that. The first one has all the interfaces, the second one has the Implementation of the interfaces and the third one uses the Interfaces for Lookup and calls the Interface methods. While deployment the Interfaces were in separate archive files.

Comment: This archive file in which the interfaces were, is it ear or jar?


If its a jar where have you placed it in glassfish?

If its a ear how do you deploy it. Or is it like all the modules are jar and they are in single ear and that ear you deploy ? 

Thanks

Comment: I made a small mistake in my last comment. The Interfaces are in both archives. One archive is a jar, which contains the interfaces and Beans. The other is a war, which contains the Interfaces and Servlet, which uses the above code for instanciation. The deployment in production environment is a special staging process. In developement deployment with the eclipse glassfish plugin.